# The specified value is out of range when trying to delete a parent shape

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete a parent shape when clicking on a child shape using this code

```
Sub DeleteParent()
  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ParentGroup.Delete
End Sub
```

I get a "The specified value is out of range" error. But, when I ungroup then regroup the parent shape, it works without problems.
Why is it not possible to delete an existing grouped shape without ungrouping then regrouping again?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you assign the macro to the shapes before or after you grouped them?

Comment: I have a grouped shape with one GroupItem containing the macro. Then I duplicate this grouped shape and change the GroupItem name by code.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I try this on another PC it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try it the way MS sites does it [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.parentgroup][1]

```
Sub DeleteParent()
  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).GroupItems(1).ParentGroup.Delete
End Sub


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.parentgroup
```

Comment: I tried this solution firstly but it didn't work for me because my shape already exists, while in the example the shapes are created, grouped and deleted in the code.